# Lombok SuperBuilder Inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, spring-boot-jpa

I've a class BaseEntity:

[image]

and an extended class:

[image]

I'm trying to build a seeder using the builder:

[image]

I want Lombok to create a constructor in the BreedEntity with the base class baseEntity.

I read the documentation and it works just fine when I delete the @entity anotation
[SuperBuilder Docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder)

Can someone explain in more detail why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, There must be a public no-argument constructors for Entity.

Spring library is designed that way. Let's say you make a query `BreedRepo.findById(...)`, following things happen

- Hibernate accesses the database driver and get the query result.
- A new class instance of `BreedEntity` is created. (You need the no arg constructor for this)
- Then all the cloumns registerd in `BreedEntiry` are set using the setter methods. (You also need to make the setter methods for each `@Column`)

**Conclusion:** Lombok builder is not compatible with Spring JPA. Use `@Data` instead

You will have to do this in  not so cool looking way, `new` then `setX`, `setY` ...

Comment: No, Hibernate doesn't exactly work like this, it doesn't call the setters but uses reflection to set the fields.

Comment: I requested this as a new feature almost two years ago: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1397. Unfortunately it never got a response from the maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add a package private constructor for Hibernate, then you can almost achieve the desired functionality.

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
BreedEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
@Getter
@MappedSuperclass
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class BaseEntity
```

and

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(...)
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class BreedEntity extends BaseEntity
```

it works in my case. If it does not work for you for some reason. You can investigate these [examples](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/lombok/src/main/java/com/baeldung/lombok/builder/inheritance) and understand how to fix your issue.